# How to use find element function of selenium in case of no attributes for name, id, class etc. in the HTML

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to make a automated login on a website using Selenium. I did everything except cant get to selenium write the login details in the appropriate boxes. Because the `driver.find` function cant find the specified element of the page or I just suck at it.

For reference I've attached the images for which I want to use the find element on(highlighted in the images):[image: the part where e-mail is to be inserted by selenium]

[image: the part where password is to be inserted]

Also need help in click function of selenium on the following:

[image: Link here]

I tried using driver find element function by class, class name but cannot understand which value do I have to insert. I did also use driver find elements but still didn't work either.

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML and your code trials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below XPath expression for email field:

```
//input[contains(@type,'email')]
```

And below one for password:

```
//input[contains(@type,'password')]
```

`driver.find_element()` code would look like below:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[contains(@type,'email')]").send_keys("your email address here")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[contains(@type,'password')]").send_keys("your password here")
```

Comment: what to do the same, but this time for clicking the button(3rd image)??

Comment: Its very similar to 'email' and 'password'. Try to construct the XPath expression by yourself, and if it doesn't work write it here in the comment what you have tried.

Comment: managed to write it by the XPath expression you provided where I replaced input for button and type also button and it worked.